# How to reorganize posts before outputting

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have an article application. Normally I do not have any recommendation system other than getting latest 100 data from database and than recommending them depending on like count. I wonder how I can get the data into an array and than do some math before outputing. I have an idea but couldn't find anything useful about how to do it in the internet.

So lets say I have this query:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(100)->get();
```

Now what I want to do is creat another `array` with size of **100** and place each article id one by one but depending on my algorithm.

before I start I want to give you everything that will be used:

```
$article->likecount 
$article->viewcount 
$article->user->reputation  
$article->category->interest
```

I will use these values in orther to re-order last 100 articles and than `paginate`  them.

Here is what I need:

- I need to get `$article->likecount`
- Add `$user->reputation`
- Add the `$category->interest`
- `Result` minus `$article->viewcount`

And than put this value inside the array. Array needs to be ordered **smallest to the largest**.

I can do something simular in **C** or **C++** but I do not know enough syntax to accomplish this in raw **PHP** or **Laravel**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Eloquent results is a Collection with a bunch of useful methods. In this case you can use `sortBy` with callback function:

```php
$articles = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')
                     ->with(['user', 'category']) // add with to optimize your query relations
                     ->take(100)->get();


$sorted = $articles->sortBy(function($article) {
    return $article->likecount + $article->user->reputation + $article->category->interest - $article->viewcount;
});

// and here is sorted array with 100 articles.
$articles_sorted = $sorted->values()->all();
```

If you would like to sort by desc use `sortByDesc()` method.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do with **->with(['user', 'category'])**

Comment: By the way $articles_sorted is not paginatable isn't it? cuz it basicaly an array

Comment: @Nikonah: without `->with(['user', 'category'])` (eager loading) there be additional queries in each iteration in `sortBy` when you accessing related models. One for get user and one to get category. With 100 article records you generate additional 200 queries! Check docs about eager loading. And yes, `$articles_sorted` is an array as you ask in question. If you want to 'paginate' it you can use `$sorted->values()->forPage($page_num, $number_of_items)`.

Comment: I see now. I needed to make a playground in orther to see the result. For now it looks like what I wanted. thanks for helping, tho I will return to this post if I need any further assistance

Comment: I wonder if I can somehow paginate the result. is there a way? or should I do it manually,